# Is it possible to lose RS Anniversary cake

Tags: runescape

Does [RS Anniversary cake](https://runescape.wiki/w/RS_Anniversary_cake) have any vulnerabilities and be lost instead of put on cooldown?

Can it be converted to rot by [Ghasts](https://runescape.wiki/w/Ghast)?

Can it be lost if used on others, in co-op slayer, or to heal NPCs?

**Edit: The cake is no longer edible**

Comment: While I cant be sure because theres no info on the wiki and I havent tested it myself, I would say none of your concerns could happen. Just cause it heals you doesnt mean that it automatically has properties other food has. Plus, in the event that you do lose it, you can always reclaim it from Party Pete.

Comment: @KyleRone when destroying, it says _"You can reclaim this from Party Pete during a RuneScape Anniversary (January) in Falador party room."_, which makes it sound like it can't always be recovered

Comment: You are correct phflack. Once the event is over, the cake is more than likely going to be removed (it was removed after previous events).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is impossible to lose it permanently. Eating it will not consume it and you will get the following message:

> You eat the delicious cake and it magically reappears.

You may destroy it but you will be able to reclaim it from Party Pete during an anniversary event which usually happens in the first week of January.